# android build failed with 'Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+.'

Tags: android, ionic2

I just added the admobpro plugin in my ionic2 project and i have tried [tutorial](http://technotip.com/5113/adding-admob-in-ionic-2/) for add admobpro pluggin, Without the plugin installed the project builds fine but once I install the plugin building fails and I get this error in  terminal:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.

> 
Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+.

 Searched in the following locations:
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/maven-metadata.xml

     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/
     file:/Users/chaitanya/Documents/software/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/maven-metadata.xml
     file:/Users/chaitanya/Documents/software/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/
 Required by:
     :android:unspecified


* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.



BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 10.896 secs

Error: Error code 1 for command: /Users/chaitanya/desktop/ionic2/NearByApp/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/chaitanya/desktop/ionic2/NearByApp/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

version and pluggin info from package.json file,

```
 "dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.4.8",
"@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
"@angular/core": "2.4.8",
"@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
"@angular/http": "2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
"@ionic-native/core": "3.1.0",
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.4.4",
"@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^3.4.4",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.1.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.1.0",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"ionic-angular": "2.3.0",
"ionic2-rating": "^1.2.0",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
"sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
"zone.js": "0.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
"typescript": "2.0.9"
},
      "cordovaPlugins": [
"cordova-plugin-whitelist",
"cordova-plugin-console",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar",
"cordova-plugin-device",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
"ios",
{
  "platform": "ios",
  "version": "",
  "locator": "ios"
}
],
```

Comment: have you added "play-services-ads" in android sdk? you need check your android sdk manager

Comment: i have add 'play-services-ads' then its working. thank you!!